# Expected value of rolling 4,5,6 vs 6,6,6

Tags: probability, expected-value

I think I'm confused about something very basic with the definition of expected value. Consider the question of "what's faster to get on average rolling dice: consecutive $4,5,6$ or consecutive $6,6,6$"?

I understand the following intuitive argument why $4,5,6$ should be obtained faster: if we fail after getting $4,5$, our failure could still be a $4$ that starts a new chain, whereas if we fail after getting $6,6$, our failure cannot be a $6$ and we need all three values again.

More formally, if $X$ is the random variable that measures the number of tries until first getting $4,5,6$, and $Y$ is the same for $6,6,6$, I think it's true that for any given $N$, $P(X=N) > P(Y=N)$. For $X=N$ to be true, we need throws $N-2,N-1,N$ to be $4,5,6$ and then also that no $4,5,6$ occurs before that, which disqualifies a number of sequences. But in the parallel case $Y=N$ more sequences are disqualified, because for instance throw $N-3$ cannot be $6$ at all - the winning triple helps disqualify more sequences.

So far this seems logical, if $P(X=N) > P(Y=N)$ that just says that for any given $N$ it's more likely that $4,5,6$ first occurs at $N$ than $6,6,6$ does. But the formal definition of expected value is $E_X=\sum_N{P(X=N)*N}$, and if each $P(X=N)>P(Y=N)$, doesn't it follow automatically that $E_X>E_Y$? What am I missing?

Comment: $P(X=3) = P(Y=3) = 1/216$. One way to understand the difference in expected waiting time is to note that 666, unlike 456, has initial substrings which equal final substrings of itself (namely 6 and 66). As a result, some of the occurrences of 666 in a long string of rolls, do not "end" a waiting game for 666 because the initial 6 or  66 in it marks the end of the previous game. With 456, all occurrences end a waiting game, so the expected waiting time is $216 = 1/(1/216)$ (as in a simple geometric RV), but with 666 the average waiting time is longer as some occurrences straddle two games.

Answer (score 1):

We can make a Markov chain.  Let $a$ be the expected number of rolls if we haven't started the run, $b$ be the expected number of rolls if we have the first number, $c$ be the expected number of rolls if we have the first two numbers.  If we are after $6,6,6$ we have 
$$a=1+\frac 16b+\frac 56a\\b=1+\frac 16c+\frac 56a\\c=1+\frac 56a\\
a=6+b\\c=6+\frac 56b\\b=1+1+\frac 5{36}b+5+\frac 56b\\\frac 1{36}b=7\\
b=252,a=258,c=216$$

If we are after $4,5,6$ we have
$$a=1+\frac 16b+\frac 56a\\b=1+\frac 16c+\frac 16b+\frac 46a\\c=1+\frac 16b+\frac 46a\\
a=6+b\\c=5+\frac 56b\\b=1+\frac 56+\frac 5{36}b+4+\frac 56b\\\frac 1{36}b=\frac{35}7\\
b=210,a=216,c=180$$
So from start $4,5,6$ takes $216$ rolls and $6,6,6$ takes $258$ on average

Comment: Thank you. While I can follow this solution, I could use some help connecting it to the formal definition of expected value. E.g. the *a* that you're calculating, formally, must be the expected value of some random variable A that measures the no. of tries until we have e.g. 6,6,6, right? What sample space is A defined on? Is it the space of all finite sequence of rolls, or all infinite sequence of rolls on which we look at finite prefixes to see what happens? In either case, what's the value of A on outcomes that never include 6,6,6 at all?

Comment: It doesn 't matter whether you consider the sample space to be arbitrarily long finite sequences or infinite sequences of rolls.  The chance that you never get $6,6,6$ is zero either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think your assumption is in fact incorrect. If for any N: $P(X = N) \gt P(Y = N)$, then $P(X = N) = P(Y = N)$ since both have to sum to $1$. Try to formulate the problem as a Markov chain.